# ArcMap Symbol levels get mixed up in multiscale representations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, representation

I have created several representations for a road network on different scales. As many of the roads are displayed as cased lines, I use symbol levels to control the drawing order. I then have saved everything in layer files to import or to process with further tools (overpass etc.)

I created a template document with multiple layers for the different scales. They show/don't show depending on the scale set, ie

- Scale 1 visible at 1:3,000,000 --> Representation 1
- Scale 2 visible at 1:1,000,000 --> Representation 2
  ...

A representation has different rules and I sort them in the symbol level window corresponding to the hierarchy of the road and attributes like bridges and tunnels, for instance:

Representation 1:

- Motorways (Bridges)
- Primary Roads (Bridges)
- ...
- Tertiary Roads
- ...
- Pedestrian (Tunnel)

and so on.

These rules and their order are properly saved in the layer files and show just fine when I load a single file into a document or the template. However loading more of my multiscale layers into it, they start to mix up. Have a look here on the first load of the scale of 1:500,000:

[image: Symbol layer of Roads upon first load with layer file for the scale of 1:500,000]

Now if I add another layer file, for instance 1:50,000, these entries totally mix up and consecutively mess up the drawing and the export:

[image: Symbol layer of Roads after 2nd load of another scale set]

That is certainly complete rubbish as I do not want to re-sort them everytime (they do get updated once a week) and furthermore will not save properly after a third of forth layer is added.

I tried a clean document and all other tricks that I knew, but I cannot resolve this issue. Some scales will maintain their original order, some won't. But I cannot try every combination of 7 scales and different representations for roads, railways, etc.

I am pretty sure it is caused by  ArcMap itself.